# How can I store multiple images in a database with a Blazor application?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

I have an application that shows a form to the users. The form is taken by the server and stored in a database where the information can be read on another page in the application. Part of the form takes an image, where the image is converted to a Base64 string and sent to Azure to be stored, and the URL to the image is stored in the database as a string. This all works fine. My trouble comes from trying to implement a feature where users can select multiple images.

I tried changing the `string Image {get;set;}` to a `List<string> {get;set;}` where the database would just store a list of the URLs where I could iterate through them in the application. This obviously did not work, as through some research, I learned that databases cannot store lists.

I am now wondering what I can do here. Is there a simpler way of doing this that I'm missing? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is more a database concept question. What database are you using ? Short answer : for SQL you need to use two table. One with user id and other info. One with the image URLs + userId. For MongoDB you can use list. MongoDB is document database, a document can contain other document.

Comment: Remi is right if you are using sql you have to create another table to save the id of photo and have it linked with the main table, or you if you have postgres sql you can save image id as Guid and it does support List<Guid>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried changing the string Image {get;set;} to a List
> {get;set;} where the database would just store a list of the URLs
> where I could iterate through them in the application. This obviously
> did not work, as through some research, I learned that databases
> cannot store lists.

You can try to use the following methods:

1. Add separator between the Image urls. Use `string Image {get;set;}` to store the image urls, the value like this: "image1url,image2url,etc" (use the `,` as the separator). You can consider using the [String.Join Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-5.0#System_String_Join_System_Char_System_Object___).
2. Create a new Image table to store the Image information (contains ID, Name, Urls), then configure one-to-many relationship between the Main table and the Image model. In the Main model, use navigation property to add the Image. Code like this:

   ```
    public class Main
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Image> Images { get; set; }
    }
    public class Image
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
    }
   ```

   More detail information about the Entity relationship, see:

   [Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key)

   [Configuring One To Many Relationships in Entity Framework Core](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/one-to-many-relationship-configuration)

   [Saving Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/related-data)